# Writing a new instance method for a common class in rails 3 globally accessible in the whole app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In which file could I add a new method to a common class, like String, Array etc, so that all models can reuse the method?

For example, in user.rb I can define:

```
class String
  def strip_non_word_chars
    self.gsub!(/(\W)/," ")
  end
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

But other models cannot use the new strip_non_word_chars method. I want it to be useable by all models...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe one place would be in an initializer file in the `config/initializers` directory. Although I'm not sure if this is common for your task.

Comment: Ya config/initializers would be the place to put it.

Comment: Thanks raidfive. I tried and this worked. I put the methods in String.rb file under initializer and String class are now equipped with the new method.